# Error starting local server through docker

Tags: java, mysql, docker, playframework, docker-swarm

I try to run the server locally according to this instruction, https://github.com/Backendless/BackendlessPro, but the following errors appear:

```
bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    | 15:46:40.634 [ERROR] c.b.u.j.ExceptionLogInterceptor |main|  Error during SQL query execution.
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    | 
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:829)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:449)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:242)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.backendless.waiting.MySQLWaiter.waitForMainDB(MySQLWaiter.java:37)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.backendless.waiting.MySQLWaiter.waitForAccessibility(MySQLWaiter.java:23)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.backendless.inject.config.WaiterInjectorConfig.configure(WaiterInjectorConfig.java:22)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:61)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:347)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:104)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule.configure(Modules.java:214)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:61)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:347)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:104)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:137)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:105)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:78)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:200)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at play.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceBuilder.java:211)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at play.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.java:121)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at play.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.java:32)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at play.api.ApplicationLoader$JavaApplicationLoaderAdapter$1.load(ApplicationLoader.scala:181)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:53)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:29)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    | 
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor19.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:949)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:819)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   ... 27 common frames omitted
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: bl-mysql
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1368)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1302)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:133)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    |   ... 30 common frames omitted
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    | 15:46:40.639 [INFO] WaiterService |main|  SQL database 'main_backendless' is not accessible. Error message: Communications link failure
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    | 
    bl-swarm_bl-server.1.tod8u2icjwt1@docker-desktop    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.. Waiting for 3000 millis before retry...
    a840@MacBook-Pro-840 scripts %
```

I will provide the logs of the process launch, there are many errors, but I do not understand them, I will be glad if someone can help.

```
ID                          NAME                              IMAGE                                                                                                            NODE             DESIRED STATE   CURRENT STATE              ERROR                                                                                                                                                                     PORTS
mfr7ozmci73cxze5388heu46a   bl-swarm_bl-coderunner-java.1     backendless/bl-coderunner-java:6.6.3.7@sha256:0e3920f996cd900e4723b2e95c017ef05f5717f902aa7a9320f128d21abda939   docker-desktop   Running         Running 12 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                               
q9w9u924m8uqmi2nnmgs1lul4   bl-swarm_bl-coderunner-js.1       backendless/bl-coderunner-js:6.6.3.7@sha256:775fb7cf9af8154ae690b74ad2ef0aa3d68e226bdd4dc1079b8b64733622855b     docker-desktop   Running         Running 12 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                               
s5s7d8k3emldknske84v5wb02    \_ bl-swarm_bl-coderunner-js.1   backendless/bl-coderunner-js:6.6.3.7@sha256:775fb7cf9af8154ae690b74ad2ef0aa3d68e226bdd4dc1079b8b64733622855b     docker-desktop   Shutdown        Complete 12 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                              
lx0x94nzost6k2h6vtr8j8f82    \_ bl-swarm_bl-coderunner-js.1   backendless/bl-coderunner-js:6.6.3.7@sha256:775fb7cf9af8154ae690b74ad2ef0aa3d68e226bdd4dc1079b8b64733622855b     docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 14 minutes ago      "task: non-zero exit (137): dockerexec: unhealthy container"                                                                                                              
hqr09wwgurcvy8z7tvtxxrlvw   bl-swarm_bl-config-loader.1       backendless/bl-config-loader:6.6.3.7@sha256:5bfa3253298dbe34073fde36fa310a714862fdd27d34d4233c594f534826a793     docker-desktop   Shutdown        Complete 13 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                              
r4uelf7gj0lhlkk1mtms81vzs   bl-swarm_bl-consul.1              consul:1.1.0@sha256:681fa1f035a7f32310d9133eefec0d0a389f09440831fd6aea818d4c0a461c95                             docker-desktop   Running         Running 14 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                               
o2ntv0b42abc7yu9vepvvpb67   bl-swarm_bl-hazelcast.1           backendless/bl-hazelcast:6.6.3.7@sha256:0781d47a9d6b7186e9d24ffbeb4be70abd3079aa2a03bdb7142cd7c2b54414c9         docker-desktop   Running         Running 10 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                               
55afhj7l4qffvxgjb4p92nop6    \_ bl-swarm_bl-hazelcast.1       backendless/bl-hazelcast:6.6.3.7@sha256:0781d47a9d6b7186e9d24ffbeb4be70abd3079aa2a03bdb7142cd7c2b54414c9         docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 12 minutes ago      "task: non-zero exit (137): dockerexec: unhealthy container"                                                                                                              
hdx0gov78wy6302k02dm5wlwa   bl-swarm_bl-mongo.1               mongo:4@sha256:5417e3110b5a905241261ceadeac7c9a53d7c0596b4bf808d1d4e2433b9e6716                                  docker-desktop   Running         Running 12 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                               
rokeivzougmxxo9uqrcqfglys   bl-swarm_bl-mysql.1               mysql/mysql-server:8.0@sha256:e30a0320f2e3c7b7ee18ab903986ada6eb1ce8e5ef29941b36ec331fae5f10b2                   docker-desktop   Running         Preparing 59 seconds ago                                                                                                                                                                             
wkjhyxkq9a9ddhaszlz3jf3yr    \_ bl-swarm_bl-mysql.1           mysql/mysql-server:8.0@sha256:e30a0320f2e3c7b7ee18ab903986ada6eb1ce8e5ef29941b36ec331fae5f10b2                   docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 59 seconds ago      "unhealthy container shutdown failed: cannot stop container: bl-swarm_bl-mysql.1.wkjhyxkq9a9ddhaszlz3jf3yr: tried to kill container, but did not receive an exit event"   
y20s8zi6ln52ykqv3upa38841    \_ bl-swarm_bl-mysql.1           mysql/mysql-server:8.0@sha256:e30a0320f2e3c7b7ee18ab903986ada6eb1ce8e5ef29941b36ec331fae5f10b2                   docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 3 minutes ago       "task: non-zero exit (1)"                                                                                                                                                 
s58is3flbio7pzxhsnvsjle0j    \_ bl-swarm_bl-mysql.1           mysql/mysql-server:8.0@sha256:e30a0320f2e3c7b7ee18ab903986ada6eb1ce8e5ef29941b36ec331fae5f10b2                   docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 3 minutes ago       "task: non-zero exit (1)"                                                                                                                                                 
l6ffodd7kxdsahb6n7as3bb2g    \_ bl-swarm_bl-mysql.1           mysql/mysql-server:8.0@sha256:e30a0320f2e3c7b7ee18ab903986ada6eb1ce8e5ef29941b36ec331fae5f10b2                   docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 3 minutes ago       "task: non-zero exit (1)"                                                                                                                                                 
xsnbcjzh2qgd37h2zo4nnjsnn   bl-swarm_bl-redis-debug.1         redis:4@sha256:2e03fdd159f4a08d2165ca1c92adde438ae4e3e6b0f74322ce013a78ee81c88d                                  docker-desktop   Running         Running 13 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                               
gw01p0n8bnpnvh80uatuapcqr   bl-swarm_bl-redis.1               redis:4@sha256:2e03fdd159f4a08d2165ca1c92adde438ae4e3e6b0f74322ce013a78ee81c88d                                  docker-desktop   Running         Running 13 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                               
uxontpct0rucfypcw49d41kcl   bl-swarm_bl-rt-server.1           backendless/bl-rt-server:6.6.3.7@sha256:d602e78c7844308cbe052569cb626894154f94081ed0a84748f013b9459eb81f         docker-desktop   Running         Running 11 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                               
jcm8ma3g04lrylabgy65ydnxk    \_ bl-swarm_bl-rt-server.1       backendless/bl-rt-server:6.6.3.7@sha256:d602e78c7844308cbe052569cb626894154f94081ed0a84748f013b9459eb81f         docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 11 minutes ago      "task: non-zero exit (137): dockerexec: unhealthy container"                                                                                                              
os0wghihvjvdyinbodp2nfliq    \_ bl-swarm_bl-rt-server.1       backendless/bl-rt-server:6.6.3.7@sha256:d602e78c7844308cbe052569cb626894154f94081ed0a84748f013b9459eb81f         docker-desktop   Shutdown        Complete 13 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                              
0ucyw3q6buiw0ng0t54tg7rd7    \_ bl-swarm_bl-rt-server.1       backendless/bl-rt-server:6.6.3.7@sha256:d602e78c7844308cbe052569cb626894154f94081ed0a84748f013b9459eb81f         docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 15 minutes ago      "task: non-zero exit (137): dockerexec: unhealthy container"                                                                                                              
x3dtqazlczfg7jsjh1ifa3lhb   bl-swarm_bl-server.1              backendless/bl-server:6.6.3.7@sha256:c29351a272b6e5e0b1240aa0d3ca8f512eb7ef4bd52e7137b161b8be521fbba2            docker-desktop   Running         Starting 3 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                               
tod8u2icjwt10h590e70474bw    \_ bl-swarm_bl-server.1          backendless/bl-server:6.6.3.7@sha256:c29351a272b6e5e0b1240aa0d3ca8f512eb7ef4bd52e7137b161b8be521fbba2            docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 3 minutes ago       "task: non-zero exit (137): dockerexec: unhealthy container"                                                                                                              
bwkjgneq2q0a92esjcdwerrf6    \_ bl-swarm_bl-server.1          backendless/bl-server:6.6.3.7@sha256:c29351a272b6e5e0b1240aa0d3ca8f512eb7ef4bd52e7137b161b8be521fbba2            docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 7 minutes ago       "task: non-zero exit (137): dockerexec: unhealthy container"                                                                                                              
ovn9pi3rymy5yfp9q67bg8zsv    \_ bl-swarm_bl-server.1          backendless/bl-server:6.6.3.7@sha256:c29351a272b6e5e0b1240aa0d3ca8f512eb7ef4bd52e7137b161b8be521fbba2            docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 11 minutes ago      "task: non-zero exit (137): dockerexec: unhealthy container"                                                                                                              
l2echsjo803fjjogmpd0ik38q   bl-swarm_bl-taskman.1             backendless/bl-server:6.6.3.7@sha256:c29351a272b6e5e0b1240aa0d3ca8f512eb7ef4bd52e7137b161b8be521fbba2            docker-desktop   Running         Running 16 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                               
ps2b41pde9afcfkziwu12h0lh   bl-swarm_bl-upgrade.1             backendless/bl-upgrade:6.6.3.7@sha256:4ea21a1a1a3555cced54088e598a91ae7a982bd55bd376e2b8c24c315d7addf6           docker-desktop   Running         Running 16 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                               
q9asqe4gtcr5sra7p930znlqw   bl-swarm_bl-web-console.1         backendless/bl-web-console:6.6.3.7@sha256:2c3bc6b8a5f19e4e09662049cd40cdb48dd4c519686879fa8bdedb30cb07fa28       docker-desktop   Running         Running 7 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                                
y6xp8n5qvni7ineunwu1hmzcy    \_ bl-swarm_bl-web-console.1     backendless/bl-web-console:6.6.3.7@sha256:2c3bc6b8a5f19e4e09662049cd40cdb48dd4c519686879fa8bdedb30cb07fa28       docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 8 minutes ago       "task: non-zero exit (137): dockerexec: unhealthy container"                                                                                                              
hu61em11ssndynph6umfx9nge    \_ bl-swarm_bl-web-console.1     backendless/bl-web-console:6.6.3.7@sha256:2c3bc6b8a5f19e4e09662049cd40cdb48dd4c519686879fa8bdedb30cb07fa28       docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 10 minutes ago      "task: non-zero exit (137): dockerexec: unhealthy container"                                                                                                              
qb8yi2bx1000bina0rp0sgw9i    \_ bl-swarm_bl-web-console.1     backendless/bl-web-console:6.6.3.7@sha256:2c3bc6b8a5f19e4e09662049cd40cdb48dd4c519686879fa8bdedb30cb07fa28       docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 11 minutes ago      "task: non-zero exit (137): dockerexec: unhealthy container"                                                                                                              
n43oc9btvhahv9cyfc98sh6wt    \_ bl-swarm_bl-web-console.1     backendless/bl-web-console:6.6.3.7@sha256:2c3bc6b8a5f19e4e09662049cd40cdb48dd4c519686879fa8bdedb30cb07fa28       docker-desktop   Shutdown        Failed 13 minutes ago      "task: non-zero exit (137): dockerexec: unhealthy container"
```

Do you have any ideas?
Operating system MacOs Monterey 12.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL container appears to have been killed, so the other apps cannot connect to it. And your other containers are dying with 137 exit codes, indicating your Docker settings do not have enough memory to run all the containers. Go into the Docker Desktop preferences and give it more memory, then try again.

Comment: I did this, even earlier, but the errors did not disappear
[Screen](https://ibb.co/2Y1WWVy)

Comment: It is possible that 7.25GB is not enough RAM. Especially when running over 10 containers on the same machine

Comment: Could it be that my Macbook doesn't meet the system requirements? I have a 2015 MacPro, Core I5 2.7 GHz, 8 RAM

Comment: Of course, thank you very much, I will think about upgrading my computer

Comment: The README there does say only 4GB is necessary, so perhaps you should open a Github issue instead. 137 error code is almost always memory related

Comment: I think these are irrelevant requirements) At the moment, the space on the SSD takes about 12 gigabytes, so I think that the RAM requirements have also increased